# Can the label "per page" on lists made look different than the links next to it?

Tags: bug, design

Lists of questions etc show links to select the count of items per page on the lower right. Next to it, there is a separate describing label with the text "per page".
Because the label has just the same design as the links nearby, it looks to me like another similar link.

(From the relation to the other links, I expected that it provides a way to specify other item counts not covered by the links, eg. "200" or "all")

Can the label be changed to look different?

Like on meta.stackoverflow.com, where the "per page" label uses just plain text.

See below for an example of the relevant lower part of a question list page:

[image: Example of the relevant lower part of a question list page]

Compare the design of the label "per page" and the related number links with this example from meta.stackoverflow.com:

[image: Example similar to proposed change]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot so that we're all talking about the same thing?

Comment: It's been that way for a long time, but sooner or later Jin or one of his minions will look at this. I can't say that I have a strong feeling about it.

Comment: @dmckee Oh, btw, screenshots added